# Magento 2 Some configurable products not shown on frontend

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I have noticed some of my configurable is not showing on the frontend, nor searchable. However, the product page is accessible directly with URL.

These products which are not showing on the frontend (but accessible with URL), have exactly the same setup as those are displayed correctly.

I have tried the following, but it didn't help.

I tried to clear cache `php bin/Magento cache:flush`

I tried to reindex `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

I tried to deploy static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

And in admin, I have made sure the products are enabled, and Visibility set to Catalog, search.

[image]

[image]

I have made sure that the child products is in_stock, and both child products and parent product are assigned to the correct website and categories.

What did I miss?

Comment: have you checked stock inventory?

Comment: I did, they are in stock. and stock status is in_stock

Comment: Have you assigned "Product in Websites"?

Comment: I would make sure the child products 1) have a positive inventory and 2) make sure the child products are enabled for the site you're using.

Comment: @xxx have you checked my comment?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I have assigned both child products and parent product to the right websites and categories.

Comment: did you use "cart to quote not to order" like module

Comment: @MagentoLearner Did you ever find a working solution? I have the exact same problem after migration. Some options are not shown in frontend. It seems to be related to qty or stock status of some items, but can't figure out what is the problem. If Visual Swatch is enabled for color attribute it works, but not with dropdown.

Comment: Same here for a few products. Not sure what's causing it or how to troubleshoot. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please Check the Following Step

> - On the inventory tab, mark availability as 'In Stock'.
> - Ensure there is a simple product associated.
> - Ensure the simple product has availability marked as 'In Stock'.
> - Ensure the simple product has qty set above the out of stock quantity threshold.
> - Ensure both the simple product and configurable product is associated to the correct website.
> - On the General tab of the configurable make sure Visibility is set to something other than not visible individually.

**Re-index (System > Index Management > Select All > Submit).**

Comment: What if all of the above is done and yet it doesn't show up? I'm gravedigging here but I'm just in the same position of the original poster

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when creating a configurable product through importing CSV. I have missed out website and store id while creating the product.  Please ensure you have configured store and website attributes to the product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar issue when creating a configurable product on Magento 2.4.x using "Duplicate" way.

What I missed is this part - Stock Status - which by default, after Magento done duplicating the product, it will be set as "Out of Stock" as [@Divyesh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/59039/divyesh) mentioned.

[image]

I spent around 20 minutes to refreshing cache & index, triple-check child product and etc.